# PHP_CodeSniffer, PHPMD or PHP Depend

Tags: php, code-analysis, static-analysis

I am looking at doing some static code analysis of an exisiting PHP project, and I'm having trouble understanding the distinctions between PHP_CodeSniffer, PHPMD, and PHP Depend. Are these simply alternatives to the same problem, or do they complement each other in some ways? Why might a developer choose one over the other?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Shameless copy from http://phpqatools.org

> ***pdepend***
>
> pdepend can generate a large set of software metrics from a given code base. These values can be used to measure the quality of a software project and they help to identify the parts of an application where a code refactoring should be applied.
>
> ***phpmd***
>
> phpmd scans PHP source code and looks for potential problems such as possible bugs, dead code, suboptimal code, and overcomplicated expressions.
>
> ***phpcs***
>
> phpcs tokenises PHP, JavaScript and CSS files and detects violations of a defined set of coding standards. It is an essential development tool that ensures your code remains clean and consistent. It can also help prevent some common semantic errors made by developers.

So no, they are not just alternatives. PDepend and PMD focus on on software metrics while PHPCS defines rules based on patterns in the token stream. PDepend doesnt care the slightest about finding Coding Standard violations. You should use all three of them. If possible in your Continuous Integration server, for instance [Jenkins](http://jenkins-php.org/).

Comment: Thanks for posting such a clear answer, and for the positive shaming to encourage me to start using a CI server.

Comment: Having recently set up all three (and more) on Jenkins for our PHP projects, I can heartily recommend all three tools.

Comment: Still the use of pdepend additionally to phpmd is not clear. Phpmd also generates metrics (and has splendid plugin for Jenkins) and can be used real-time in PHPStorm.
What would pdepend do for me what I cannot get from phpmd?

Comment: @AlexanderPalamarchuk well, isn't it obvious from the documentation? http://pdepend.org/documentation/software-metrics/index.html is quite different from http://phpmd.org/rules/index.html. Except for NPath and Cylcomatic Complexity, there is little overlap.

Comment: @Gordon And also things like "Number Of Methods", "Lines Of Code", "Coupling Between Objects" etc. I mean logically these tools seem rather similar.
I would correct my opinion that yes, **pdepend** provides features for package metrics, and it can be considered as a reason to use instead of **phpmd**. But together it is quite annoying. You have to configure the same parameters in two different products.
Besides **pdepend** cannot be built-in in PhpStorm so it's hard to control its inspections on-fly. So I don't see how to use it in Continuous Integration.

Comment: @AlexanderPalamarchuk pdepend creates jdepend reports. Those can be published via Jenkins and they are quite different from PMD reports in Jenkins (the latter are focussing on design flaws, not raw metrics). Just enable both and see the difference. Apart from that, no one forces you to use either or.

Comment: Also worth a look at [php-cs-fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/) which attempts to fix the errors generated from phpcs.